# Cascading Dropdown source file

Tags: 2010, development, 2007, solution-package, solution

I have a solution (wsp) called CascadingDropdown.wsp which is of SharePoint 2007, now I would like to use it for 2010 and modify it a little bit, my question is: where would I be able to find a source for this solution?

I couldn't find directly, maybe someone could help?

I saw that there are some different popssibilities to achieve cascading dropdown's but as this solution already exists and used I would like to continue using it later as well ... but for this I need to modify and migrate to SharePoint 2010 and later to 2013.

This solution has one list with values and then it can have 3 cascading drop down list.

Update:

I found more information about that it comes from this: 
http://datacogs.com/datablogs/archive/2007/08/26/641.aspx

But the page is not available anymore and the source code as well ... anyone know if I would be able to find it somewhere else, or maybe anyone has it?